# Performing styling action on specific data in a highcharts graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a data where each point corresponds to each month of the year. For example,
`{01:5, 02:8, 03:12, 04:16}` and so on, up to the last month of the year. However, a lot of this data is extrapolated by a polynomial regression in my flask app.

I have this data made into a highcharts column chart very similar to this one:
http://jsfiddle.net/DwyY8/

My goal is to apply a style to dates that have not yet happened to imply they are extrapolated data (for example, something like making them more transparent)

How would one go about this?

Comment: In addition to @yarl's answer you could make 2 series. One is the "real" data and the other is the extrapolated set. Change the series properties on the 2 sets to differentiate them.

Comment: what result you want. can u give sample of output

Comment: Wergeld, that was an idea I had but I'm not quite sure how to make highcharts plot this the same way it previously plotted the other data

Comment: @Crowz, you would force the color/marker/etc for each series to be identical. Not the best idea though. So what we did (using a spline series) is set the "real" data series to have a solid line and the projected data series to use a dotted line. For the bar chart you have I really like yarl's answer - hence I did not make my suggestion an Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's not perfect, but using only CSS you can apply eg.:

```
.highcharts-series rect:nth-child(n+4) {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gv6pX/)

Comment: Okay, did not know you could do that!

Comment: I've heard it does not have wide browser support, is this true?

Comment: AFAIK `nth-child()` is part of CSS3. According to [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) _The :nth-child() selector is supported in all major browsers, except IE8 and earlier._